# Meta tags in angular 6 not updating per component

Tags: angular, facebook, twitter, seo

I'm trying to update meta tags (title, description) per component, As angular is SPA we don't have the luxury of putting meta tags in the head section of every page. SO tried doing it using `Meta` feature of angular to update on every component load. 
It shows the tags being changed to desired but when i share link to facebook or twitter it does not show the updated tags but picks the original tags present in index.html

screenshot of index page
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GU9by.png)

screenshot of detail component
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PyCSt.png)

Im using this library to update meta tags .

```
import { Meta } from '@angular/platform-browser'; 

this.meta.updateTag(
  { name: 'title', content: title },
    `name='title'`
  );
  this.meta.updateTag(
  { name: 'description', content: des },
    `name='description'`
  );
  this.meta.updateTag(
  { name: 'image', content: img },
  `name='image'`
);
```